How do I find the right size cap to close a water valve?
There is a valve under my sink.  It has two outlets: one to the sink faucet, and one to the dishwasher.  I want to cap off the one that goes to the dishwasher.  I can measure that the threads on the valve stem itself are 9/16'' outer diameter.  On the water supply line that's currently connected to this valve stem, the compression fitting nut is 5/8'' wide.  The supply line itself is 9/16'' in outer diameter.  What cap do I need to buy to cap off this valve stem?
This is a question on the same problem, but neither it nor any of its answers address how to determine the exact cap to buy.
Edit
It appears to be the case that you can go to a hardware store and there will be multiple products labeled "3/8'' cap", and these product will be different sizes.  What I'm asking is how to determine which of the products labeled "3/8'' cap" is the actual cap I need for the purpose I've described, if that is indeed the actual measurement.
The most reliable way to do this is to work in actual measurements.  That's why I've specified that 9/16'' is the actual outside diameter of the (male) threads I want to fit over, and that the nut currently fitting over those threads has an actual width of 5/8''.  The cap I bought labeled "3/8'' cap" has an actual inner diameter to its (female) threads of 9/16'' and a total actual width of 3/4''.  It doesn't fit, but that doesn't mean that a different cap sold under the label "3/8'' cap" won't.
So, I need to know actual measurements of the actual cap I need to buy so that I can confirm in the store that it's the product that will cap this valve.
Edit 2: Resolution
The accepted answer is substantially correct.  Here are the details.
If your valve stem has threads with an outer diameter of 9/16'', then you have a standard under-sink valve.  This stem can be capped with a 3/8'' compression cap.  The "compression" part is important, as other caps marked 3/8'' will not actually fit.  The cap will be 5/8'' wide.
You will also need a washer to create a leakproof fitting.  The 3/8'' compression cap requires a washer with 1/2'' outer diameter.  I found that a Hillman 3/16 x 1/2 x 1/16 works perfectly.  I also recommend teflon tape for the threads.

With plumbing, it is usually the inside diameter of the pipe/outlet that matters, not the outside.

@crip659 Thanks for the tip.  I understand, but I have no good way to measure the inside diameters of these things.

Plumbing connections can be a bit of a pain. In the US there are "pipe thread," "compression," and "flare" in common use. Perhaps the obnoxious thing about them is that none of the threads measures according to the "nominal" or "trade" size they're called by. This is why in the hardware store you find multiple caps all marked 3/8" size whose appearance and actual physical dimensions differ.
Each has its purpose, and particularly in some sizes, it can be difficult to recognize at a glance or even with a measurement which kind one is dealing with. The male flare fitting always has a smooth, tapered nose - so if your valve doesn't have that then it's definitely not flare. Differences between male pipe thread and male compression are that the pipe thread is a coarser pitch; the compression is machined smooth inside and usually has a clear shoulder maybe 1/4" down inside the throat of the fitting.
The connection on your shutoff valve is almost certainly 3/8" compression. Why? Because that's just what's common for sink supply hoses in the US. Tapered pipe thread  ("IPT") is sometimes used in this particular spot and flare only seldom. How to measure it? There's a tip sheet from Zoro with all the details -- in the chart at the bottom it indicates that the male threads of a 3/8" tube compression fitting are 9/16" OD.
There are two easy ways about this:

DIY plumbing repairs always require at least two trips to the hardware store.. so in the first trip buy one of everything that might be applicable, and in the second trip return those that weren't.
Remove the dishwasher hose and take it to the store with you. There's usually a board with sample fittings you can use to test-fit the hose and discover which size and type it is.

Also - in case the cap doesn't work out (doesn't seal), you could replace the valve itself with the single-port type.

"DIY plumbing repairs always require at least two trips to the hardware store.. so in the first trip buy one of everything that might be applicable, and in the second trip return those that weren't." Definitely words to live by, for more than just plumbing. Doing that has saved me many additional trips to the hardware store (and similar types of stores for DIY projects).

If you have a standard shutoff valve for US plumbing you need a 
3/8 cap with a washer.

Agree, but just to add that if your old shutoff is, well, old, then you might consider a new quarter turn unit with a single outlet.

Thank you.  I bought a cap labeled "3/8'' FIP", and it is too loose to fit over the valve stem.  The inner diameter of its threads is 9/16'', which is the same as the outer diameter of the threads on the stem I'm trying to fasten it to, so it just slides over the stem.

What country are you in?  As I said standard US plumbing fixtures are 3/8  for shutoffs in the kitchen.

I cannot understand how 3/8 slides over 9/16, or your measurements are incorrect.  There is no standard 9/16 plumbing fixtures in the US.  Maybe you have a 1/4" shutoff or a combo with a 3/8 and a 1/4 port.

Maybe the OP could add a picture…

I'm in the U.S.  I've triple-checked my measurements.  From another forum, I've discovered that it's possible I bought a 3/8'' cap for a different purpose that uses a different measuring system, so that it isn't the same size as the 3/8'' cap you've suggested I buy.  In that case, what I'm asking is how to determine which cap that's labelled 3/8'' is the actual one I want to buy.

This is why plumbing is terrible: fip isn’t mip isn’t npt isn’t flare isn’t … anyway, the npt is almost certainly what you want.

@AloysiusDefenestrate I can maybe add a picture, but that sounds complicated and it likely won't be today.  Can I expect that the product I need to buy will say "NPT" on it?

Yup, 3/8NPT….  (assuming your plumbing is from the last 50 years)
